# limiting concurrency in javascript node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I have the following code:

```
const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream(__dirname + '/../resources/profiles.txt'),
        terminal: true
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
        scrape_profile(line)
    }
```

scrape_profile is a function that makes some request to the web and perform some processing. now the issue is that i wanted to limit so that 5 scrape_profile is executed per 30 seconds.. as of now if i have a text file with 1000 lines, it would go ahead and execute 1000 concurrent requests at one time.. how do i limit this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're using a `readlineInterface` if you're asynchronously reading the entire file into memory at once, so for my answer, I've replaced it with a call to `fs.readFileSync` as it's much easier to deal with finite values than a stream and the question didn't explicitly state the file IO needed to be streamed.

You could try using [`Bluebird` `Promise.reduce`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const lines = fs.readFileSync('./test.txt').toString().split('\r\n');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const BATCHES = 5;

const scrape_profile = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Done with", file);
        resolve(Math.random());
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
});

const runBatch = batchNo => {
    const batchSize = Math.round(lines.length / BATCHES);
    const start = batchSize * batchNo;
    const end = batchSize * (batchNo + 1);
    const index = start;
    return Promise.reduce(lines.slice(start, end), (aggregate, line) => {
        console.log({ aggregate });
        return scrape_profile(line)
            .then(result => {
                aggregate.push(result);
                return aggregate;
            });
    }, []);
}

runBatch(0).then(/* batch 1 done*/)
runBatch(1).then(/* batch 2 done*/)
runBatch(2).then(/* batch 3 done*/)
runBatch(3).then(/* batch 4 done*/)
runBatch(4).then(/* batch 5 done*/)
 // ... preferably use a for loop to do this
```

This is a full example; you should be able to run this locally (with a file called 'test.txt' that has any contents), for each line it will spend a random amount of time generating a random number; it runs 5 separate batches. You need to change the value of `BATCHES` to reflect the number of batches you need

Answer (score -1):

you can use setinterval for 30 seconds to perform a loop of scrape_profile for 5 times, your loop is using the number of lines which is like you specified 1000 lines without stopping, then make a loop for 5 times and put it in a function that you call with setinterval and of course keep the index of the current line as a variable too to continue from where you left off